# Calculating average of values in raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, average

I want to get the average of values in a raster. How do I get this using Raster Calculator?

I was looking for this kind of function: `AVE("yourraster@1")` in the raster calculator.

Answer (score 1):

In the Raster Menu, select Miscellaneous and then Raster Information.

Select the raster and tick the box that says "Read and display image statistics (force computation if necessary)".

The gdal command is:

```
gdalinfo -stats "path to image"
```